# How to get rid of "None" result (not in a function)

Tags: python

```
import time
print("Welcome to password manager.\n")
time.sleep(1.5)
x = input(print("Do you want to store a new account 『c』, login 『l』, or exit 『e』?: "))
```

Comment: It's `input("Do you want .....")`, there shouldn't be any `print` here.

Comment: Do not edit your post to say `solved`. Either pick an answer that made you solve it, or deleted your post. Also, if you're going to keep the post around, even if you think it's been solved, you're not using SO for yourself, you're using it for yourself and every future visitor, so [edit it to actually describe the problem and contain a question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `print()` inside the `input()` method. The `input()` method takes only a string:

```
import time
print("Welcome to password manager.\n")
time.sleep(1.5)
x = input("Do you want to store a new account 『c』, login 『l』, or exit 『e』?: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
import time
print("Welcome to password manager.\n")
time.sleep(1.5)
x = input("Do you want to store a new account 『c』, login 『l』, or exit 『e』?: ")
print(x)
```